# How to add a url link for a region using google geo-chart api?

Tags: google-maps, google-visualization, google-geolocation

The given code bellow produces a simple region vice world map and render some data on mouse hover. API document shows a click even can be added but unfortunatly I dint find any document on it how can I add a url link for another web page  to a particular region (country).

I short when I clicked on a region/country it should render associated page that holds detailed information provide by my data base application.

```
<html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages':['geochart'],
            // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
            // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
            'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
          });
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

          var j = "{{ind}}".replace(/&quot;/g,"\"")

          function drawRegionsMap() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

              ['Country', 'Popularity'],
              ['Germany', 200],
              ['United States', 300],
              ['Brazil', 400],
              ['Pakistan', 500],
              ['France', 600],
              ['RU', 700],
            ]);

            var options = {};

            var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="regions_div" style="width: 1400px; height: 1200px;"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: check this answer --> [geochart regions clickable urls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38598129/5090771)

Comment: @WhiteHat This was a great Idea thanks