# google chart obtaining position in select event listener

Tags: google-visualization

I have the following google chart:

```
    var elms=xml.getElementsByTagName("overall")[0];
    var avgs=elms.getElementsByTagName("average");
    for(var i=0;i<avgs.length;i++){
          chartArr[0][i+1]=avgs[i].getAttribute("name");
          chartArr[1][i+1]=parseFloat(avgs[i].getAttribute("avg"));
    }
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartArr);  
    var options = {
        title: 'Average Club Rating',
        is3D: true, 
        width:1200,
        chartArea:{
          width:800,
          left:92
        }
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('averagechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
       console.log(this.getPosition());
    });
```

If you look, i first populate the `charArr` then i create and setup the google chart.

On the bottom, you'll see the addListener call. What I want is when that element is clicked, a custom url most likely from the chartArr is used and determines the endpoint location.

How do I get the position of the listener so i can grab the custom url which is going to be created.

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38598129/5090771), although for a map chart, it should work the same...

Answer (score 0):

I dont really sure to understand your request, but you can print the event with this method,

```
console.log(chart.getSelection());
```

Regards,